# Duplicate content in LEFT JOIN query + get count on joined table

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to join two tables with similar ids, then get a sum of two fields as well. let me explain:

**test table:** id | post | desc | Date

**likes_dislikes table:** id | song_id | user_ip | like | dislike

on test 'test table', the 'id' matches that of the likes_dislikes 'song_id', so I tried LEFT JOIN since not every post will have an id in the likes_dislikes table, but I got duplicate results .

```
SELECT *
FROM
  test
  LEFT JOIN likes_dislikes ON test.song_id = likes_dislikes.page_id
GROUP BY test.song_id
ORDER BY test.id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```

how can I prevent the duplicate content, and also, get the TOTAL likes/dislikes associated with each post as I run through a while loop?

Comment: What values from `likes_dislikes` are you wanting to return? Do you actually want/need the `user_ip`, or just a count of the `like/dislike`?

Comment: In other words, what should your final output be? `id, post, desc, date, num_likes, num_dislikes`?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I need returned

Comment: Are `like/dislike` null or zero or what?

Comment: they're zero by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assume you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    T.`id`,
    T.`post`,
    T.`desc`,
    T.`Date`,
    COUNT(L.`like`) as `LikeCount`,
    COUNT(L.`dislike`) as `DislikeCount`
FROM `test` T
    LEFT JOIN `likes_dislikes` L
       ON T.`Id` = L.`song_id`
GROUP BY T.`Id`, T.`post`, T.`desc`, T.`Date`
ORDER BY T.`id` DESC;
```

Comment: since it selects only id and post, can I not get the desc and Date? or do I have to add those in the query if I need them?

Comment: that WORKS!! and how would I access the likes count and the dislikes count? i tried both `$row['Like'] and $row['LikeCount']`

Comment: @Keezy OK. Lets look at the issue deeper. Can you show full script?

Comment: hope I didn't have you looking at this too long trying to figure it out. your code works perfectly I must have been too tired or something yesterday but I tried it again a few minutes ago and it works exactly as I hope. thank you very much!